# Would self-hosting ChatGPT be feasible, w.r.t. computation costs?

Tags: open-ai, chatgpt, open-source

Suppose the pre-trained, current date (2023-02-04) ChatGPT model was released open source, would it be feasible for regular users to interact with the model on a self-hosted computer?

### Assumptions

1. I assume getting output based on some input is, at least, hundreds of times faster than training such a model.
2. I assume no additional output parsing/input limitations are used. In particular I can imagine all the boiler plate to keep the ChatGPT model(s) acting politically correct etc. may be a significant overhead. This is to be ignored for this question.

### Data

So far I've found the ChatGPT 3.5 model to have [175 billion parameters](https://lifearchitect.ai/chatgpt/):

[image]

Though I do not yet know how large that is in `Mb` nor do I have an idea on how long generating an output would typically take.

Comment: 175 billion parameters means at least 175 billion numbers, means it's probably in the range of 175GB (if all numbers are 1 byte - unlikely) - 1.4 TB (if all numbers are 64bit = 8byte, more likely).

Comment: ... and apart from storage/RAM, also need the computation power to do the math and return an answer within reasonable time. So yes, it is feasible, if you have a few hundred thousand bucks to spend I guess.

Comment: Ah, don't forget the cooling and electricity bill.

Comment: @kutschkem Thdd we numbers are half-precision, so 175B parameters is 350 GB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, I assume the ChatGPT architecture is similar to the published GPT-3 model [1].

The [Transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer_(machine_learning_model)) architecture used for GPT3 is much more memory-bound than compute-bound at a high parameter count and a low context size. A large batch size (3.2M across ~few thousands GPUs for GPT-3) is used during training, but relatively low computational power is needed at the inference time for non-batched applications such as real-time chat. OpenAI is probably batching multiple users' requests to improve the throughput.

GPT-3 has 175B parameters and would require 326GiB memory to store the weight in float16. *Quantization* methods are proposed to reduce the memory required to store model weights, where the model weights are stored in lower precision. In the GPTQ paper [2], the authors have shown that large GPT models perform almost as good as the original model with 4-bit per parameter, reducing the 175B model to less than 90GiB. 3-bit quantization is also considered, reducing the size to less than 70GiB.
Note that additional memory required for internal states is small compared to the weights, especially if a [memory-efficient attention](https://github.com/facebookresearch/xformers) is used.

Recently, such quantization methods have gained attention due to the release of the pre-trained [LLaMA](https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama/) models.
Some people are running 65B LLaMA model even CPU-only [3] [4] with a reasonable throughput.

Therefore, for the question of whether it would be possible to run a 175B model in a home computer, I would say it is currently stretch but certainly possible if somewhat slow responses are acceptable.

- [1]: Brown, Tom, et al. "Language models are few-shot learners." Advances in neural information processing systems 33 (2020): 1877-1901. https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.14165
- [2]: Frantar, Elias, et al. "GPTQ: Accurate Post-Training Quantization for Generative Pre-trained Transformers." (2022). https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.17323
- [3]: [Satyajit Ghana on Twitter](https://twitter.com/thesudoer_/status/1634883960525422597)
- [4]: [Taiga Takano on Twitter](https://twitter.com/tg3517/status/1635095157480759297)

Answer (score 4):

> Suppose the pre-trained, current date (2023-02-04) ChatGPT model was released open source, would it be feasible for regular users to interact with the model on a self-hosted computer?

No, assuming it's regular, consumer hardware. However, some open-source alternatives  aim to be runnable on consumer hardware, e.g. https://github.com/LAION-AI/Open-Assistant (not released yet):

> We want to do this in a way that is open and accessible, which means we must not only build a great assistant, but also make it small and efficient enough to run on consumer hardware.

Comment: the moment this becomes feasible, every thing changes again, for good and for bad.